# Use enviroment variable from httpdconf in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've set an env variable in our .conf to see if the application is running on a development environment or on production. I've set it like this:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV dev_dev
```

In my .htaccess I want to set the folder for the domain as a root, on the development server the url will be http://website.com/example/ but on the production environment will be http://website.com

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=FOLDER:]

RewriteCond %{ENV:APPLICATION_ENV} dev_dev
RewriteRule .* - [E=FOLDER:example]
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SetEnv` you need to use `SetEnvIf`.

So replace this line:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV dev_dev
```

with:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^ APPLICATION_ENV=dev_dev
```

and restart Apache.